# CSS3 Input Selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS3 selector like jQuery's [:input](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) which returns all input fields: `select`, `input`, `textarea` and `button`?

Even a browser-specific implementation would be fine, as long as it's CSS-only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Not directly, no](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors). However you can work around this with the [`:enabled` and `:disabled` selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#UIstates):

```css
:enabled, :disabled {
    ...
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/k6W3s/1).

Comment: Disappointing that it's not part of any draft, but the `:enabled` property seems to be perfect for my situation. To clarify, the enabled property only applies to `<button>`, `<input>`, `<optgroup>`, `<option>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` - which is perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
textarea, input[type] {
    /* Your styles here */
}
```

Above selector will applied to all textareas and any input that has a type attribute.

Comment: Inputs without a type default to `text` — specifying that the input must have an explicit type attribute isn't really helpful in the context of the OP.